# Retrofit2 custom interceptor not working in SDK 25 and above

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an OkHttpInterceptor which intercepts every request made by the App to append an `token` in the request header.

```
private OkHttpClient getOKHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("x-access-token", getNewTokenPassively());
            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
         }
    }).build();
}
```

I am using this method add an interceptor

```
....
return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getOKHttpClient())
                .build();
....
```

This is not working in SDK 25 and above where, any http call `call.enqueue` methods does not work and API call never goes through...

if I replace `.client(getOKHttpClient())` with `.client(newOkHttpClient.Builder().build())` everything works fine.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: maybe update to latest version of retrofit will help?

Comment: Nothing is visible on the loggin interceptor for okhttp... This is very weird and I am not able to find any similar issues. Updated retrofit to 2.3.0 and still it is not helping. I am completely clueless. The same API call works if I put a break point.

Comment: just as a suggestion add a dependency for okHttpClient : api "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0"

Comment: I added it, but no luck. Still `call.enqueue` does not seem to make a network call. It randomly ignores it.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem and have modified the question accordingly.